# Preview android xml layout outside of eclipse/ADT

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way to render an xml layout from an android project outside of eclipse/ADT?

To be extremely clear, I'm not asking to view some random xml file marked up like an android layout xml file. A layout could reference custom views and anything that would provide a preview needs to be able to load such a resource. So really, anything out there?

Comment: follow with Barcardi bat answer.

Comment: I followed, but the answer deals with an answer to the question as being a side effect of what i might consider an accepted answer. I'm looking for just a renderer.

Answer (score 2):

You view this in [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) Tool. Download the tool [here](http://code.google.com/p/droiddraw/downloads/detail?name=droiddrawr1b23.jar&can=2&q=). Hope this may help you.